# String to Marker -- Android Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a google maps marker object that I am trying to store in an sqlite DB. The only primitive type that the marker can be converted to is a string from what I know with the

```
marker.toString();
```

method. Is it possible to go from String to marker when I am retrieving from the sql lite DB or is this impossible?

Comment: Can't use use several methods/values from the Marker to store multiple values in your database? For example the latitude and longitude of `marker.getPosition()`. These can be used to recreate the marker.

Comment: Yes I figured that was the way to go about it. I thought a marker object could be stored more directly but I'll go about it this way. Thanks.